# What is 2-2+2 ? a-b+c = (a - (b+c)) or (a+(-b+c))?

Tags: arithmetic

I am little bit confused for manipulating bigger maths, So i am asking a simpler version. According to BODMAS we do first addition then Subtraction.

a-b+c = (a - (b+c)) or (a+(-b+c)) ?

Comment: If this question two upvotes, then two downvotes, then two upvotes, you'll be up two votes. Applying this logic to your two expressions, you should be able to see which of them makes sense when $a=b=c=2$.

Comment: One trick I sometimes find helpful:  type your expression into some suitable software.  Wolfram Alpha, say, accepts "$2-2+2$" exactly, Excel takes "$=2-2+2$".  Vary the numbers to see which meaning is assigned.

Comment: I don't know, I would say addition and subtraction have the same priority and perform the operations from left to right. That is, $2-2+2=2$. In order to avoid confusion, use parentheses!

Comment: In my opinion, BODMAS (or PEMDAS, depending on where you live), is a very misleading mnemonic, for exactly this reason. The convention for order-of-operations is brackets, opposites, (multiplication and division), (addition and subtraction). Addition and subtraction have the same "precedence level", so you evaluate them from left to right. The mnemonic should really be more like BO(DM)(AS), but we can't pronounce parentheses. Anyways, $a - b + c = (a - b) + c$.

Comment: @HenrySwanson, I agree with you. PEMDAS, BODMAS, BEDMAS, etc. are considered "wrong" because the acronym itself is a bit misleading. You must do parentheses first, and then exponents, but when it comes to multiplication, division, addition and subtraction, you have to do which one comes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an expression like 2-2+2, it does not matter which order you place the terms, the answer is always the same- 2.

In your algebraic situation however, what you need to realize is that negative signs distribute. In other words:

$a-(b+c) = a+ (-1)(b+c) = a-b-c$

Which is not equal to a-b+c.

Your second expression is in fact correct, because positive signs do not distribute. (Strictly speaking they 'absorb,' as it were other signs.)

So,

$a-b+c=a+(-b+c)$

There are some fun analogies for associativity, commutativity, etc. as well, but perhaps those are for another post.

Answer (score 0):

You do addition and subtraction the same, but from left to right.  So in this question you do subtraction first because it appears before the addition.
$a-b+c=(a-b)+c$